# I'm having trouble calling a view by code

Tags: ios, swift2

I want to call a view , but when I do a black screen .
This view that I want to call is a SWRevealViewController ( menu), your storyboard id is "initial " .
I'm calling as follows:

```
 let modal = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("initial"))!
 self.presentViewController(modal, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Anyone know what is wrong ? thank you.

Comment: from which viewcontroller are you calling it from ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your viewController is setup correctly?  Have you tried loading it directly on its own to make sure it looks correct?

Comment: @Shubhank ConfirmController.. but this view isn't a viewcontroller of the menu

Comment: @Dancreek If I call trough a viewcontroller menu works, but when I call the confirmController he is black screen ... the storyboard id is correct.

Comment: does your view controller have any view inside it?

Comment: @MohsenShakiba yes

Comment: managed to solve the problem , the id was wrong, thanks